# Run a shell command from an web excel dropdown

Tags: excel, snmp

i was given as a challenge next topic:
At work we have all the data for our switches grouped in an web excel sheet.
Is there any way of creating a dropdown option  in a cell so that we can power the switch on?
I have a snmp command that works but i don t know how to use it in web excel.
So could i have two options let s say ON/OFF as a dropdown in excel that would send a snmp command?
Thank you

Tried with vba but is not allowed web excel.

Comment: In Excel?  Yes.  In web Excel?  No.  Did you really mean Excel in the browser?

Comment: Hi, yes, i meant exactly web version. We use it from a sharepoint as a team.

Comment: You cannot launch external processes from a web site.  That would be a huge security flaw.